# What does AI mean? (inductance factor )

Tags: inductance

If we consider the formulas N^2 / R = L and L / Al = N^2, we get the Al value given in the core datasheets as the opposite of the resistance. What does this mean?

What is the meaning of Al except that it is the inductance value in a winding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Core, Inductor, Inductance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/621950/core-inductor-inductance)

Answer (score 0):

In your first equation, R is magnetic reluctance, not resistance. The Al factor is provided to make it easy to determine the inductance for a given number of turns (or to find how many turns are needed for the desired inductance) for a core. From your equations you can see that the Al factor is the reciprocal of reluctance.